# Store and retrieve binary image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have saved Image in database as binary :

```
 Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog fd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            ILogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fd.FileName));

            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
            binaryImage = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(binaryImage, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }
           _merchantInfo.Logo = binaryImage;
```

I want to read the image and showing it image tool, I tried this:

```
        _merchantInfo = new MerchantInfo();
        _merchantInfo = _context.MerchantInfo.FirstOrDefault();

        byte[] binaryPhoto = (byte[])_merchantInfo.Logo;
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(binaryPhoto);
        _merchantLogo = new BitmapImage();
        _merchantLogo.StreamSource = stream;

        ILogo.Source = _merchantLogo;
```

No Error, But the image does not showing in image box :(

Is there error in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using try/catches elsewhere in your application, that might be catching exceptions from this code?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? Please edit that one and add more details about what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: @Clemens, It's different questions !!, but anyway I have solved this question and I will add the final answer. Thanks any way

Comment: Ok, but seriously you need to give more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will, Thanks Clemens :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved this, here is the code for store and retrieve the image in database as binary :

To store the image:

```
       Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog fd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            ILogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fd.FileName));

            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
            binaryImage = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(binaryImage, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }

        _merchantInfo.Logo = binaryImage;
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Image retrieval and display:

```
        merchantInfo = new MerchantInfo();
        _merchantInfo = _context.MerchantInfo.FirstOrDefault();

        byte[] binaryPhoto = (byte[])_merchantInfo.Logo;
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(binaryPhoto);
        _merchantLogo = new BitmapImage();
        _merchantLogo.BeginInit();
        _merchantLogo.StreamSource = stream;
        _merchantLogo.EndInit();
        ILogo.Source = _merchantLogo;
```

Thanks for everyone helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

Universal Binary Storage  Method -> You must read all the bites of the picture/file and save them in a binary array.

```
OpenFileDialog FileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

byte[] BinaryData = new byte[]{};

if(FileDialog.ShowDialog())
{
   BinaryData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Binary Retrieval(For Images Only in WPF) -> You must set an BitmapImage and store all the binary information within it with the help of a MemoryStream.

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
byte[] binary = new byte{}; /* <--- The array where 
                            we stored the binary 
                            information of the picture*/

image.BeginInit();
image.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(binary)
image.EndInit();
```

Universal Binary Retrieval and Binary File Upload Method ->

```
byte[] BinaryData = new byte[]{};

private void Download()
{
   OpenFileDialog FileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

   if(FileDialog.ShowDialog())
   {
     BinaryData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileDialog.FileName);
   }
}

private void Save()
{
   OpenFileDialog FileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

   if(FileDialog.ShowDialog())
   {
     using(System.IO.Stream stream = new File.Open(FileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
     {
           using (var BinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream))
           {
                                                    
               BinaryWriter.Write(BinaryData);
               BinaryWriter.Close();
           }
     }
   }
    
   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i create this class and i am using it without any problems, try it and share it.

```
/// <summary>
/// created by Henka Programmer.
/// Class to make the converting images formats and data structs so easy.
/// This Class supporte the following types:
/// - BtimapImage, 
/// - Stream,
/// - ByteImage
/// 
/// and the other option is image resizing.
/// </summary>

public class Photo
{
public BitmapImage BitmapImage;
public System.IO.Stream Stream;
public byte[] ByteImage;

public Photo(Uri PhotoUri)
{

    this.BitmapImage = new BitmapImage(PhotoUri);
    this.Stream = new MemoryStream();
    this.Stream = this.BitmapImage.StreamSource;
    this.ByteImage = StreamToByteArray(this.Stream);

}
public Photo(Bitmap Photo_Bitmap)
    : this((ImageSource)(new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(Photo_Bitmap)))
{
    /*
    ImageSourceConverter c = new ImageSourceConverter();

    byte[] bytes = (byte[])TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Photo_Bitmap).ConvertTo(Photo_Bitmap, typeof(byte[]));
    Photo ph = new Photo(bytes);*/
}
public Photo(ImageSource PhotoSource) : this(PhotoSource as BitmapImage) { }
public Photo(BitmapImage BitmapPhoto)
{

    this.BitmapImage = BitmapPhoto;
    this.ByteImage = GetByteArrayFromImageControl(BitmapPhoto);
    this.Stream = new MemoryStream();
    WriteToStream(this.Stream, this.ByteImage);
}
public Photo(string path)
{

    try
    {
        this.Stream = System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        this.BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        BitmapImage.BeginInit();
        BitmapImage.StreamSource = Stream;
        BitmapImage.EndInit();
        this.ByteImage = StreamToByteArray(this.Stream);

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}

public Photo(byte[] byteimage)
{

    this.ByteImage = new byte[byteimage.Length];
    this.ByteImage = byteimage;
    // WriteToStream(this.Stream, this.ByteImage);
    //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteimage);
    this.Stream = new MemoryStream(byteimage);
}

private void WriteToStream(Stream s, Byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(s))
    {
        writer.Write(bytes);
    }
}

private byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream inputStream)
{
    if (!inputStream.CanRead)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    // This is optional
    if (inputStream.CanSeek)
    {
        inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    byte[] output = new byte[inputStream.Length];
    int bytesRead = inputStream.Read(output, 0, output.Length);
    Debug.Assert(bytesRead == output.Length, "Bytes read from stream matches stream length");
    return output;
}

private BitmapImage BitmapImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        imageStream.Write(ByteImage, 0, ByteImage.Length);
        imageStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.StreamSource = imageStream;
        image.EndInit();
        //image.Freeze();

    }
    return image;
}

public BitmapImage GetResizedBitmap(int width, int height)
{

    ImageSource imgSrc = CreateResizedImage(this.ByteImage, width, height);
    return new Photo(GetEncodedImageData(imgSrc, ".jpg")).BitmapImage;
}

private ImageSource CreateResizedImage(byte[] imageData, int width, int height)
{

    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();

    bmpImage.BeginInit();

    if (width > 0)
    {

        bmpImage.DecodePixelWidth = width;

    }

    if (height > 0)
    {

        bmpImage.DecodePixelHeight = height;

    }

    bmpImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageData);

    bmpImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;

    bmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

    bmpImage.EndInit();

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
    {

        drawingContext.DrawImage(bmpImage, rect);

    }

    RenderTargetBitmap resizedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(

    (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height, // Resized dimensions

    96, 96, // Default DPI values

    PixelFormats.Default); // Default pixel format

    resizedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

    return resizedImage;
}

internal byte[] GetEncodedImageData(ImageSource image, string preferredFormat)
{

    byte[] returnData = null;

    BitmapEncoder encoder = null;

    switch (preferredFormat.ToLower())
    {

        case ".jpg":

        case ".jpeg":

            encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

            break;

        case ".bmp":

            encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();

            break;

        case ".png":

            encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

            break;

        case ".tif":

        case ".tiff":

            encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();

            break;

        case ".gif":

            encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();

            break;

        case ".wmp":

            encoder = new WmpBitmapEncoder();

            break;

    }

    if (image is BitmapSource)
    {

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image as BitmapSource));

        encoder.Save(stream);

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        returnData = new byte[stream.Length];

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);

        br.Read(returnData, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        br.Close();

        stream.Close();

    }

    return returnData;

}

public byte[] GetByteArrayFromImageControl(BitmapImage imageC)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageC));
    encoder.Save(memStream);
    return memStream.GetBuffer();
}

public ImageSource ToImageSource()
{
    ImageSource imgSrc = this.BitmapImage as ImageSource;
    return imgSrc;
}

public System.Windows.Controls.Image ToImage()
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Image Img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    Img.Source = this.ToImageSource();
    return Img;

}

}
```